# arch linux apache start at boot crash

Tags: configuration, arch-linux

I have Raspberry Pi B+ with Arch Linux installed and at boot time, apache web server does not start:

```
[xxx@rpi ~]# systemctl status -l httpd
* httpd.service - Apache Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 1970-01-01 01:00:23 CET; 45 years 0 months ago
  Process: 177 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=134)

Jan 01 01:00:23 rpi apachectl[177]: Assertion 'canonical' failed at src/nss-myhostname/nss-myhostname.c:204, function fill_in_hostent(). Aborting.
Jan 01 01:00:23 rpi apachectl[177]: /usr/bin/apachectl: line 79:   185 Aborted                 (core dumped) $HTTPD -k $ARGV
Jan 01 01:00:23 rpi systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=134
Jan 01 01:00:23 rpi systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Web Server.
Jan 01 01:00:23 rpi systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 01 01:00:23 rpi systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jan 01 01:00:24 rpi systemd-coredump[208]: Process 185 (httpd) of user 0 dumped core.
[xxx@rpi ~]#
```

However, if restart apache from ssh terminal (after system restart and ssh login), the apache is ran properly:

```
[xxx@rpi ~]# systemctl restart httpd && systemctl status -l httpd
* httpd.service - Apache Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-01-05 02:48:46 CET; 336ms ago
  Process: 420 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 424 (httpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           |-424 /usr/bin/httpd -k start
           |-426 /usr/bin/httpd -k start
           |-427 /usr/bin/httpd -k start
           |-428 /usr/bin/httpd -k start
           |-429 /usr/bin/httpd -k start
           `-430 /usr/bin/httpd -k start

Jan 05 02:48:44 rpi apachectl[420]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.0.154. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Jan 05 02:48:45 rpi systemd[1]: PID file /run/httpd/httpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jan 05 02:48:46 rpi systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
[xxx@rpi ~]#
```

What is going on (running `Linux octopustest 3.12.35-1-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Tue Dec 23 07:14:51 MST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux` kernel and `Apache/2.4.10`)?

Comment: see this: `since Thu 1970-01-01 01:00:23 CET; 45 years 0 months ago` in your error message. Are you shutting down your Rpi down correctly? Or do you just unplug it?

Comment: I am shutting down rPi with command `shutdown -r` for reset and `shutdown` for power off.

Comment: Maybe it is just an apache2 bug, try to upgrade your arch in the next time often use `pacman -Syu`, maybe then the bug will be solved. The problem with Arch GNU/Linux is, that always the newest _it could be that it is stable_ version is in the repos.

Comment: @LittleByBlue, I also think it is a bug, but I need this corrected ASAP. And also, that `since Thu 1970-01-01 01:00:23 CET; 45 years 0 months ago` in my log file I think that time is reported because at that moment at boot network is still offline (my rPi does not have dedicated RTC yet).

Comment: Sounds to me like apache is starting while the network ist still down, are you sure that the service is waiting for the network.target?

Comment: Apart from adding the servername to the config file (which is probably irrelevant but just in case) I would start by looking at the core file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty simple fix to this that worked for me. It requires editing the /etc/hosts file, which is always to be avoided if possible, but it fixed all problems that I have. This error will occur if anything tries to access the internet and get back information, including Apache, Eclipse, and other applications. This sometimes is caused by a bug in the applications themselves, but could also be a local problem, which is caused when your /etc/hosts file is missing some element that the program requires.

Note that you will need admin access (or to be a part of the `sudoers` group) to complete some of these steps.

First, open the hosts file using the following command: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`. Your hosts file should resemble the following, which is a direct copy of mine:

```
# 
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost BEN-PC-ARCH
::1         localhost.localdomain   localhost BEN-PC-ARCH
# End of file
```

Note that in addition to the reflection of 127.0.0.1 to localhost.localdomain, there is a second line that does the same. Adding this to the `/etc/hosts` file fixes the problem, for whatever reason.

Comment: The second entry is for IPv6 and should be standard on all Arch (and Arch ARM) installs...

Comment: Welp, it wasn't. Idk what happened to make it that way, but adding it fixed my problems.